# CSS Selector - Safe to use only [type="text"] and not input[type="text"]?

Tags: html, css

I have been wondering whether it's safe to just use `[type="text"]` instead of `input[type="text"]` in CSS.

The reason is by using `input[type="text"]`, I can't override it with a single class selector.

```
// HTML
<input type="text" class="has-error">

// CSS
input[type="text"] { color: black; } // has stronger specificity than below
.has-error { color: red; }           // won't override
```

So, is there any other element in HTML that use the `type` attribute? So far, I haven't met any other tag that uses it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following tags support the type attribute:

`<button>, <input>, <command>, <embed>, <object>, <script>, <source>, <style>, <menu>` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes))

and only the `input` tag has 'text' as a possible value for the `type` atttribute

So, yes, [`type="text"]` should do fine assuming the markup is written correctly and the rules inside such a selector will only be set on your input elements with type text.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is safe to use until you dont have other element with type attribute, but if you have like "`<ul>`" can have type attribute you will select it too,but since you are also filtering it with "text" as a type so you wont conflict with built in tags but can conflict in plugins etc and you custom tags  so make solution to have input[type="text"] instead

Comment: I never saw `<ul type="text">`. Is there a reason to use that?

Comment: yes it isnt text, so you can go with it just saying that if you have any elemnt that conflicts, it isnt built in type='text' in other

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use it with tagname ( select by tagname and filter by attribute is much faster than select all tags and filter them - you can ignore this, but batter keep it in mind )

to override do this

```
input[type="text"] { color: black; }
input[type="text"].has-error { color: red; }
```

You can check here http://jsbin.com/rayinebaro/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Hi, would you mind to explain more about "select all tags and filter them". I don't really get it. Thanks

Comment: well - to apply css rule browser should select all elements from DOM which matched by rule ( rarely think about it, but it's true ) - so the more elements - than more work browser should do

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer. But I like keeping my specificity as low as possible (which is around 1 class, 1 tag).